# Android ListView not showing at all

Tags: android, wiki

I'm learning to fill `ListView` using `ArrayList`. I've populated the `ArrayList` inside the `doPostExecute()` of `GetParentVitalsName()` using

```
vitalList.add(parentVitalName);
```

Logcat shows no error. But the List is not displaying. I'm only getting a blank page. I found that it's not going inside the `getView` method of `MyListAdapter`. what am I doing wrong here?

`acitivity_vital_list.xml` contains the `ListView` and `vital_list_layout` contains the item template

```
public class VitalListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private List<String> vitalList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vital_list);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String status = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if(status.equals("true")){
            new GetParentVitalName().execute();
            Log.d("Tag", "Execute complete");
            populateListView();
            Log.d("Tag", "Populate complete");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vital_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyListAdapter(){

            super(VitalListActivity.this, R.layout.vital_list_layout, vitalList);
            Log.d("Tag", "super okay");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //Making sure we've a view to work with(may have been given null
            Log.d("TAG","Inside get view");
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.vital_list_layout, parent, false);

            String currentVital = vitalList.get(position);

            //Fill the view

            TextView vitalText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.vitalTextView));
            vitalText.setText(currentVital);

            return itemView;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return vitalList.size();
        }
    }

    private class GetParentVitalName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            String responseText = null;

            HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/vitals/custome/added/parentvitals");
            Log.d("KMN", "Sucess");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                Log.d("DFGH","Success again.");
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.d("Http Post Response V", Integer.toString(statusCode));
                responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("Http Post Response V", responseText);

            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseText;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String responseText){

            if (responseText != null){
                try {
                    JSONArray vitalsArray = new JSONArray(responseText);
                    for(int i =0;i<vitalsArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject vitalsObject = vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String parentVitalName = vitalsObject.getString("parentVitalName");
                        vitalList.add(parentVitalName);
                        Log.d("YGVJ",vitalList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**vital_list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/vitalTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_vital_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cinch.getvitalsapp.activities.VitalListActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Vitals" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vitalsListView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you use model class?

Comment: Where is `new GetParentVitalName().execute();` code

Comment: you need to change your custom adapter. make constructor in adapter which pass an arraylist and from that list set Text to textview.

Comment: inside OnCreate(). I did not use model class

Comment: I've found the problem. vitalList.add(parentVitalName); inside the onPostExecute doesn't get added to the global vitalList... so is it possible for an asynctask to update global variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Logcat shows no error. But the List is not displaying. I'm only
>   getting a blank page

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items in Adapter data-source:

```
vitalList.add(parentVitalName);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Note:** make sure `vitalList` is same List object which is used in `MyListAdapter` Adapter class.

**EDIT:**

Also override `getCount()` method in `MyListAdapter` class:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return vitalList.size();
    }
```

Comment: I'm creatng adapter only after adding all items to my list and also not adding anything after adapter is created

Answer (score 1):

Make your Adapter Class Like below.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

Context context;
ArrayList<String> arraylist= new Arraylist<>;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> arraylist){

        super(context, R.layout.vital_list_layout, vitalList);
        Log.d("Tag", "super okay");
        this.context=context;
        this.arraylist=arraylist;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    //Making sure we've a view to work with(may have been given null
    Log.d("TAG","Inside get view");
    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null)
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.vital_list_layout, parent, false);

   // String currentVital = vitalList.get(position);

    //Fill the view

    TextView vitalText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.vitalTextView));
    vitalText.setText(arralist.get(position));

    return itemView;
}

}
```

In your Activity class. initialize adapter and put arraylist into it as shown below:

```
ListView list;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vital_list);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String status = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    if(status.equals("true")){
        new GetParentVitalName().execute();
        Log.d("Tag", "Execute complete");
        populateListView();
        Log.d("Tag", "Populate complete");
    }
}

    private void populateListView() {
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(VitalListActivity.this,vitalList); //where vitalList will be get from asynctask. 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(VitalListActivity.this,vitalList);
 this line is giving me error.. Error:(78, 81) error: incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a getCount() method overrided. Try doing that, it will work fine then.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vitalList.size();
}
```

and then try setting list to match_parent.